# istream overloading with 2nd argument being a double pointer?

Tags: c++

My question is what is the proper way to implement this, and how exactly would I make use of it? 
The operator to be overloaded has the following prototype:

```
//Reads a variable from an input stream
//A variable should have a one-word name that does not start with a digit or minus sign
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Variable** v)
```

We are given a variable class along with an equation class. I think the goal of overloading the istream operator is to make things easier when creating an equation object from a string. You can find it below.
My attempt at implementing this is as follows:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Variable** v)
{
  string i;
  in >> i;
  if (isalpha(i[0]) && i[0] != '-') 
    *v = new Variable(i); 
  return in;
}
```

Variable Class:

```
class Variable : public Operand
{
private:
  static unordered_map<string, int> vars;
  string name;
public:
  Variable(string);
  virtual int getValue() const override;
  void setValue(int);
};
```

Equation class:

```
class Equation
{
private:
  Variable* var; 
  Operand* lhs;
  operator_t op;
  Operand* rhs;
public:
  Equation(string);
  int evaluate();
  //Should also implement copy constructor and copy assignment (rule of three)
  ~Equation();
};
```

Comment: There is no "universally proper way". It all depends on the application. Who is responsible for creating the jobs. How they are created. How they are destroyed. Maybe the overload should only be invoked on pointers to objects that are already constructed, and the only thing the overload does is initialize its contents. All of these questions are something that you must answer yourself, and your own answer will guide the actual implementation.

Comment: I don't think reading into a pointer-to-a-pointer is a very good idea at all, and even a reference to a pointer (which would be more "correct") just doesn't feel right, as you get into issues of who is responsible for clean-up. A reference to a smart pointer might at least be better? (And BTW, your `if` statement accepts everything bar a minus sign)

Comment: @KenY-N I'm not a fan either but I must implement it the way it is, I think my professor is trying to teach us something here but I'm completely lost. (And thank you! That slipped by, resolved it now.)

Comment: @kingk Your question lacks sufficient context to answer. We don't know how the text that you want to read is formatted and we don't know what `Variable**` is supposed to represent. We also don't know whether the caller or callee is supposed to allocate memory for the pointer. Using raw pointers everywhere is not good modern C++ style. They should probably all be by-value, `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` instead. Also, as the code comment says, without proper implementation of copy constructor and assignment the `Equation` class is broken.

Comment: *I think my professor is trying to teach us something here* Learning to suffer through stupid design decisions is a useful skill, but learning to push back against them is much more effective in the long term.

Comment: There is no proper way to "implement this" - too much is left unspecified.  Given that there is no proper way to "implement this" there is also no real way to make use of it either.

Comment: As awful as having to overload a `Variable**` is as an assignment, your implementation looks okay (under the assumption the pointer you are given is valid), which could be a bad assumption depending on a lot of things that aren't apparent with the code you have shown). Are you having a specific problem with this implementation?